# Add a paragraph using Control.Add on Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, label, web-controls

So i have a Div, and on that div i add a label, i do some operations and then i add another, the problem is that the "paragraph" using the method Control.Add doesnt occur.
.
I get something like:
"Label1""Label2".
instead of:
.
"Label1".
"Label"

Heres the code that i use:

```
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label box3 = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label();
    box3.Text = TextBox2.Text;
    box3.ID = TextBox2.Text;
    oportunities.Controls.Add(box3);
    //operations
    oportunidades.Controls.Add(box4);
```

I tried to add "trash" to do the paragraph but so far no good

Comment: What type of controls are `opportunities` and `oportunidades`?

Comment: its a div sorry if i wasnt clear enough

Comment: Let me be more specific. Is it a [`Panel`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.aspx&ei=rY7_UeifELal4AOFxoGQCw&usg=AFQjCNGtUyMJLEd_DfbfxHbgu1phpfRhMA&sig2=0hvP5ycwSnypJiNig8s45g&bvm=bv.50165853,d.dmg) or is it a [`DIV`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y7zx0ww(v=vs.100).aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a LineBreak `<br />` between the two texts:

You can do this with a Literal-Control:

```
oportunities.Controls.Add(box3);
oportunities.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
oportunidades.Controls.Add(box4);
```

Or by simply appending `<br />` to the first label:

```
box3.Text = TextBox2.Text + "<br />";
oportunities.Controls.Add(box3);
oportunidades.Controls.Add(box4);
```

Comment: wow very simple, sorry didnt knew that command thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's a caveat with this - `<br/>` break floats.

Comment: @TheSolution Could you elaborate? A float on the outer div/Panel works. And floats on the spans/Labels work as well.

Comment: @NULL, a `<br/>` works like a `clear`. So if you were trying to float an element **after** the `<br/>` it wouldn't work.

Comment: @TheSolution Now I see what you mean. But I guess that is the desired behavior anyway, according to the requirements in the question.

Comment: @NULL, sure is. It's just a caveat of `<br/>`.